# Когда отдаю большую страницу, получаю белый экран

Tags: php, nginx

Используется nginx с php fpm, и сайт на wordpress.

Когда отдается большая страница, например, с контентом в 2e6 символов (`$b = str_repeat('a', 2e6);`) я просто получаю белый экран.

Думал, OOM Killer, но dmesg развеял сомнения. Не он.

PHP INI:
https://pastebin.com/5baR4071

Nginx.conf:
https://pastebin.com/2QD9NHAD

Nginx site conf:
https://pastebin.com/aYcbHrk9

Куда глядеть?

Comment: смотрите лог ошибок PHP и Nginx

Comment: а еще укажите url запроса

Comment: Nginx отдает 200. C PHP ничего подозрительного не увидел. Там есть notice и deprecated. А там можно переключить уровень логирования? Url? https://exampe.com/test-page.

Comment: для изменения уровня логирования поставьте в php.ini error_reporting=E_ALL и если нужно выводить на экран, то еще display_errors=1 и проверьте чтобы приложение не изменяло эти опции в процессе выполнения